# Machine design tip over safety requirement?

Tags: design, safety

I am designing an automation machine. I remember that I read a document that the machine is stable if some certain amount of force to push on the top corner of the machine and the machine does not tile more than X degree then the machine is stable.

I could not find the document again. Do you see something like that online?

Comment: This is a simple static mechanics problem.  Find the center of momentum (center of mass) of the machine and draw the force diagram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Physics.SE

Comment: This actually seems more like a resource-hunting question, but regardless: off-topic.

Comment: The wording can be changed to emphasize the goal of the question. It's quite on topic to ask for a design requirement regarding machines. The op is not looking for a free body diagram, he/she is searching for the existence of the requirement. Right?